# Export a selection consisting of multiple layers in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-pro, export, select

In ArcGIS Pro, I am trying to export a selection consisting of many layers (see image), but am having trouble doing so. I know there is no way to directly export such an item, so I have to do some kind of workaround, presumably to get these all into a single layer. I would like to retain the borders between polygons within that layer as well, and I'm not sure of the best way to do that.

I've tried copying and pasting the selection into an empty feature class (didn't work at all), and I've tried merging the selected layers (didn't retain borders, didn't work in general because some of my polygons are portions of larger overall layers).

[image: My selection relative to the shapefile]

Comment: Hopefully your layers all have the same fields / schema.  Have you looked into the Append tool? You could export one layer to a new feature class, then just append the remaining layers.

Comment: The different layers were created by different people at different times, so unfortunately the fields vary quite a bit; would that still work? And would append work with portions of layers, or would I have to do layer from selection with each one that is only part of a layer? The bad news here is that I have to reproduce the solution 18 different times with different combinations of layers.

Comment: The issue here is that layers have a many to one relationship with sources. You could use FeatureClassToGeodatabase to copy a list of layer names to a geodatabase, but you might get the same record multiple times with different attributes in the resulting feature classes (based on the fields selected in the layer). Any Dissolve operation would need to be performed after the source data was copied.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about why the results of Merge tool did not meet your requirements and what you mean about preserving the boundaries/borders of your polygons?  The Merge tool should preserve all polygons for all source layers exactly exactly as they were, merely adding other fields (if the different layers had different fields).

Comment: I used Merge yesterday to do a pairwise erase on some other features, and the output was one large shapefile (not in itself a problem) with no individual polygon/borders between layers (such as the northernmost layer in my figure); I suppose at this point that's actually no longer a problem for what I want for my output, but the issue does remain that some of the polygons involved in the merge are only portions of layers and it would be inefficient to make dozens of clips and layers from selections in order to use merge for this project, so I'm on the hunt for something slightly quicker